# My gnome-terminal doesn't launch anymore after I updated to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome-terminal

Whether I try to launch it from my start menu, or from another terminal, or from the shortcut Ctrl+Alt+T, it just won't open. I can see that there is something loading, but nothing happens. When I open my files and right-click and then choose "open in terminal", gnome-terminal does open and works 100% completely.

I just updated to Ubuntu 20.04 and it worked before in 18.04.

Is there anything to check to see what the problem is?

Edit : When trying to launch it from another terminal, I get the error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "usr/bin/gnome-terminal", line 9, in <module>
      from gi.repository import GLib, Gio
   File "usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
      from . import _gi
ImportError: cannot import name '_gi'
```

Comment: I installed python 3.8 and set it as default and it worked. I think python 3.7 was broken on my laptop.

Comment: Feel free to write your finding out as an answer for the benefit of future users, and accept it. Indeed, your upgrade must have gone wrong with respect to python.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to set Python 3.9 as the default python3 version on my system. If you run this:

```
$ head /usr/bin/gnome-terminal
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

You will see that gnome-terminal is using python3, but I suppose all the dependencies were installed using Python 3.8. I could fix it by setting back Python 3.8 (manual mode) as the default Python 3 version with:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config python3
There are 2 choices for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/python3.9   2         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python3.8   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.9   2         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python3.8 to provide /usr/bin/python3 (python3) in manual mode
```

I tried to uninstall and re-install the gnome-terminal but it did not work.